# AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'accpet'

Tags: python

I was building a simple server code and i keep getting this attribute error. I dont understand why. here is my code:

```
import socket
from socket import*
from time import ctime


HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR =(HOST, PORT)

tcpsersock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsersock.bind(ADDR)
tcpsersock.listen(5)

while True:
    print("waiting for connection...")
    tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accpet()
    print("...Connected from: "),addr

    while True:
        data = tcpclisock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpclisock.send('[%s] %s' %(ctime(), data))

    tcpclisock.close()
tcpsersock.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple typo: You want [**`accept`**](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) instead of **`accpet`** (an accidental pet python?).

Answer (score 2):

try 'accept' instead of 'accpet'

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Always make sure you don't name your python file as "socket.py" as it is the name of the library.

Answer (score 0):

you have in your code:

```
tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accpet()
```

did you mean `tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accept()` ?